# ext.NET closing dynamic window

Tags: asp.net, window, ext.net

In ext.net I created a window dynamically and I want when user click a specific button, close that window.

Here is my code.parent window define this:

```
    Window win= new Window();
    win.ID = "window1";
    win.Title = "";
    win.Height = 400;
    win.Width = 750;
    win.AutoScroll = true;
    win.Resizable = false;
    win.Padding = 5;
    win.Modal = true;
    win.AutoLoad.Url = "child.aspx";
    win.AutoLoad.Mode = LoadMode.IFrame;       
    this.form1.Controls.Add(win);
    win.Render(this.Form);
    win.Show();
```

In child.aspx:

```
    Parent.window1.close(); // error
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you need...

```
parent.window1.close(); // note lowercase "p" on "parent"
```

Comment: I did it but it had error: The name 'parent' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code :
parentAutoLoadControl.close();

in javascript.